# sscanf get string until second symbol (include one)

Tags: c

How to get string until second symbol through sscanf?

for example:

```
char *str = "struct1.struct2.struct3.int";
char buf[256] = {0};
sscanf(str, "", buf); //have any format string could get string until second dot?
```

Comment: I would use loop to find position of second dot, and then simply `memcpy` that part of the `str`

Answer (score 2):

> sscanf get string until second symbol (include one)
>   How to get string until second symbol through sscanf?

Not generally possible with a single use of `sscanf()`.

Certainly, without a lot of work, a more involved use of `sscanf()` will work for many input strings, yet fail for select ones<sup>1</sup>.  `sscanf()` is not the best fit here for this task.

`strchr(), strcspn()` better suited.

```
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// Return offset to 2nd needle occurrence
// or end of string, if not found.   
size_t foo(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
  size_t offset = strcspn(haystack, needle);
  if (haystack[offset]) {
    offset++;
    offset += strcspn(haystack + offset, needle);
  }
  return offset;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  const char *haystack = "struct1.struct2.struct3.int";
  printf("<%.*s>\n", (int) foo(haystack, "."), haystack);
}
```

Output

```
<struct1.struct2>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Consider: `"struct1.struct2"`, `"struct1.."`, `"..struct2"`, `".struct2."`, `".."`, `"."`, `""`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `*` to tell scanf to ignore an element:

```
const char *str = "struct1.struct2.struct3.int";

int main() {
    char buf[256];
    int i = sscanf(str, "%*[^.].%[^.]", buf);
    printf("%d >%s<\n", i, buf);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs as expected:

```
1 >struct2<
```

because exactly 1 element was assigned even if another one was parsed.

Comment: Fails when `str[0] == '.'` as `sscanf()` stops early.  Code then prints uninitialized `buf`.  I suspect OP does not care though.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: You are right. We all know that `scanf` if only a poor man's parser. This code if not robust againt incorrect input (incorrect including empy parts)